# How to retrieve/pass current entry id within another channel entries tag pair?

Tags: playa, entryid

I am currently trying to loop through channel "promos", where each entry has a Playa field designating which entries that particular promo should display on:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="promos" orderby="promos_order"}
    {exp:playa:children field="promos_show_on_page" child_id="{current_entry_id}" var_prefix="playa"}
        <a href='{promos_link}'><img src="{promos_image}" /></a>
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

My issue is that I don't know how to pass in the `current_entry_id` to the `child_id` parameter.

Is this possible with or without any particular plugins or extensions, or am I going about this in the completely wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `playa:parents`, not `channel:entries`. Playa will infer the `entry_id` so long as you place this tag loop within the `channel:entries` tag of the entry you're viewing. (You can pass it via the `entry_id` parameter if you like.)

```
{exp:playa:parents channel="promos" field="promos_show_on_page" orderby="promos_order"}
    <a href='{promos_link}'><img src="{promos_image}" /></a>
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Comment: I though it was that the playa field was contained in the promos channel field group. Seems not.  Good catch, Derek.

Comment: Actually, that _is_ the case. But he wants to find which promos (parents) to show based on the entry he's viewing (child). These relationships can be confusing!

Comment: Yessir. Brutal.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to me like you would need the child_id param if you're looking for the playa loop to display the children of each entry in your promos entries loop of the "promos" channel.  It would do that automatically, with each loop being within each returned entry of the entries loop.  Without that parameter, the children loop would assume the parent to be the current entry.

Comment: But the `child_id` parameter is what's matching the current entry.  The parent is the promos entry.

Comment: You're already mapping it to the current entry by (a) nesting it within the entries loop and (b) by specifying within which field of the entries loop the children may be found.  If the children loop was OUTSIDE the entries loop, it would be a different story.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused or not using the correct terminology (I'm somewhat new to EE), but the children of the `promos_show_on_page` field references the pages that each promo should be displayed on.  So I'm trying to verify that the current page the user is on is included in those children, and displaying that promo if so.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here, but you should just be able to use the {entry_id} tag as mentioned in the playa docs [here](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/children.html).

**entry_id**

The parent entry’s ID(s). If your tag is within an {exp:channel:entries} tag pair, this will default to the current entry’s ID.

So you would have something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="promos" orderby="promos_order"}
    {exp:playa:children field="promos_show_on_page" child_id="{entry_id}" var_prefix="playa"}
        <a href='{promos_link}'><img src="{promos_image}" /></a>
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

***UPDATE***
Using the example I described below, you would use embed variables. Once you pass the variable and value to the embed template, you can use it instead like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="promos" orderby="promos_order"}
    {exp:playa:children field="promos_show_on_page" child_id="{embed:main_entry_id}" var_prefix="playa"}
        <a href='{promos_link}'><img src="{promos_image}" /></a>
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: But that `entry_id` is tied to the current channel entries loop, correct? I need it to reference the entry id of the actual page being viewed.

Comment: Yes, it would be the current entry in the loop. I guess I missed that you were in a multi-entry template. Sorry. So the playa field is NOT related to the entries in the channel loop?? If your playa field is in the entries under the channel "promos", that is what you would be retrieving anyway. I guess I don't understand. What entries/channel are the playa field related to and what entries/channel are you "viewing"? Is this code snippet in an embed from another template in which the playa field is related?

Comment: This code resides inside an embedded template and will display the promos in the sidebar on pages from multiple channels (pages, testimonials, etc.).  The Playa field exists in the Promos channel and displays a list of all pages (again, from multiple channels) on which each particular promo should be displayed.

Comment: If this is the case, pass the entry_id to the embed template. like this:  {embed="template_group/embed_template" main_entry_id="{entry_id}"}        Then in your embed template, use the embed value to check. I'll update my answer above to show you the difference.